# Request objects from SOAP server using suds by simple logical expressions

Tags: python, web-services, soap, suds

I'm new with SOAP and suds library, and I fight problem that I can't solve.

I Have server with SOAP interface. I need to download all it's objects with parameter A, where A is empty **and** parameter B, where B is not empty.

- Is it possible?
- Does SOAP (as protocol) allows such requests?
- Does suds supplies such requests?

I've working code, such as:

```
import suds.transport.http
from suds.client import Client

trans = suds.transport.http.HttpAuthenticated(username=username,
                                              password=password)
__client = Client(url, transport=trans)
modelthing = __client.factory.create(soap_data_type)
modelthing.instance.A = '5'
modelthing.instance.B = '7'
func = __client.service.__getattr__('ExistingFunctionRetrievesListofObjects')
func(modelthings)
```

It returns list of all objects that has A = 5 and B = 7. Works perfectly.
But it takes just exact parameters, I don't know how to set B to "not empty", I also don't know how to set A to "empty".

I tried at least set A this way:

```
modelthing.instance.A = '' #not working
modelthing.instance.A = ' ' #not working
```

then it returns me all objects with all different types of A, as if I didn't set this parameter.

Does there exist solution for my task? Is it possible to use such simple logic with SOAP? And if "yes" does suds supports it?

Comment: Did you try to remove the attribute from the object? I'm not sure about what modelthing is, but I remember having a similar issue with suds and it was solved by not sending the attribute at all. You could use `delattr(modelthing.instance, 'A')` to delete the attribute.

Comment: I've changed it to show what is modelthing. I don't want request without this parameter, I want to set this parameter to "NOT NULL". But I read about SOAP and now I feel it have to be function on server side that will allow to set such parameters as I need.
Thank you!